Bulk insert in MongoDB, but get ids of documents that were not upserted?
I'm using pymongo and I need to insert some documents and get their ids. I have a unique composite index in my database preventing insertion of duplicated items.
According to the documentation on update_many the method returns an instance of UpdateResult like this:
class UpdateResult(_WriteResult):
    """The return type for :meth:`~pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one`,
    :meth:`~pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many`, and
    :meth:`~pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one`.
    """

    __slots__ = ("__raw_result",)

    def __init__(self, raw_result: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]], acknowledged: bool):
        self.__raw_result = raw_result
        super().__init__(acknowledged)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.__raw_result!r}, acknowledged={self.acknowledged})"

    @property
    def raw_result(self) -> Optional[Mapping[str, Any]]:
        """The raw result document returned by the server."""
        return self.__raw_result

    @property
    def matched_count(self) -> int:
        """The number of documents matched for this update."""
        self._raise_if_unacknowledged("matched_count")
        if self.upserted_id is not None:
            return 0
        assert self.__raw_result is not None
        return self.__raw_result.get("n", 0)

    @property
    def modified_count(self) -> int:
        """The number of documents modified."""
        self._raise_if_unacknowledged("modified_count")
        assert self.__raw_result is not None
        return cast(int, self.__raw_result.get("nModified"))

    @property
    def upserted_id(self) -> Any:
        """The _id of the inserted document if an upsert took place. Otherwise
        ``None``.
        """
        self._raise_if_unacknowledged("upserted_id")
        assert self.__raw_result is not None
        return self.__raw_result.get("upserted")


How do I get the ids of documents that were neither inserted, neither updated ? (not upserted)
